# Multiple views of the same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am an experienced web developer, but new to rails. I am writing a budget application based on a double-entry accounting database. The database contains journal entries to represent transactions, and each journal entry has multiple postings. Each posting has an account and an amount.

Here are simplified versions of my models:

```
class Posting < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
  belongs_to :journal_entry

  attr_accessible :account_id, :amount
end

class JournalEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :postings, :dependent => :destroy

  attr_accessible :narrative, :posting_date, :postings_attributes

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :postings, :allow_destroy => :true,
    :reject_if => proc { |attrs| attrs.all? { |k, v| k == '_destroy' or v.blank? } } 
end
```

I've successfully created a nested form that allows a journal entry and its list of postings to be edited together.  However, most journal entries will be simple and have one credit entry and one debit entry.  To make the data entry easier in this case, I want to have another form that allows the user just to specify the credit account, debit account and amount.

From my research, can see  2 ways to do this:

1. Single table inheritance where SimpleJournalEntry (which extends JournalEntry)
2. Using ActiveModel to make a SimpleJournalEntry model that isn't directly attached to the database, and handle the database changes myself in the controller

The SimpleJournalEntry model would have the credit account, debit account and amount and would be used for the editing of simple records.  The existing JournalEntry model would still exist to allow editing of more complex records.

Which is the 'rails way' to handle this kind of thing?  Is there another option that I've not considered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to disagree with railsdog on this one.  I think you do have a good STI candidate.  In particular, I think "let [JournalEntry] handle the details of the simple or complicated save" demonstrates that you are dealing with two separate concerns.

If your simple and complex JournalEntries have different business logic, they should be represented by two different classes.  It is not hard to imagine, for example, that the complex JournalEntry might want to add validations that the simple JournalEntry does not.  Or perhaps the simple JournalEntry should have fewer attr_accessible declarations than the complex JournalEntry.  I would suggest:

```
class JournalEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
  # shared accessors and validations
end

class SimpleJournalEntry < JournalEntry
  # simple accessors and validations 
end

class ComplexJournalEntry < JournalEntry
  # more complex accessors and validations
end
```

I would handle these two classes with separate controllers and views.

On an unrelated note, the :all_blank option for #accepts_nested_attributes_for should do what your Proc does, no?  From the docs: "Passing :all_blank instead of a Proc will create a proc that will reject a record where all the attributes are blank excluding any value for _destroy." That is, `accepts_nested_attributes_for :postings, :reject_if => :all_blank`

Comment: Thanks for the hint on :all_blank - I must have missed that in the docs.  I was leaning towards STI but I'm not sure where I would put the `has_many :postings`.  Should that be on the base JournalEntry, and then I make virtual attributes for `credit_posting` and `debit_posting` on the SimpleJournalEntry?

Comment: I ended up going with the STI approach.  I put the `has_many :postings` on the base `JournalEntry` class.  I had to enable `:autosave` on this association because I was manually creating Postings in the SimpleJournalEntry model (based on virtual attributes for credit_account, debit_account and amount).

Answer (score 2):

I would not use STI to handle this.  Essentially you have a simple 'view' and a 'complex' view, the underlying model(s) aren't changing, just the view you want to present.

There is nothing wrong with creating alternate link (path/route) to this simple view, and managing the 'simplicity' in the save action in your controller, you'll just have to inspect the params received and decide which action to take.

Even better, pass the params as received to your journal entry model, and let it handle the details of the simple or complicated save.  After all, the business rules associated with accounting should be in the model, should they not?

Comment: How would I handle this in the journal entry model?  At the moment, I call `@journal_entry.update_attributes(params[:journal_entry])` and the ActiveModel magic takes care of setting the fields on the journal entry and postings models for me.

Comment: I read Ben's response below (which is equally valid - welcome to the world of 'tomayto' / 'tomahto').  Simplest thing that would work might be to inspect params to see if simpleCreditAcct, simpleDebitAcct, and simpleAmount were present, if so, manufacture the appropriate two postings, inject those into params as if they came from the complex form, and delete the simpleXXX params values. The model logic is the model logic.  Neither solution seems expensive to try and test out.  The key is find what works for you for understandability and maintenance.

Comment: I tried both approaches and the STI approach seems easier to understand.  Thanks for your help.